# GetLocationAsync() Never Returns - Android Mobile App

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to rectify a bug in a mobile app. When calling the below, it never returns and hangs the app.

All location permissions have been requested in MainApplication.cs under the Android platform, using:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;

[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.gps", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.network", Required = false)]
```

They are also specified in the manifest file (not sure if this is an issue).

I'm testing with a button event:

```
private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetCachedLocation().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        await DisplayAlert("Location Data", $"{_lat} : {_lon}", "OK");
    }
```

Which fires the following:

```
public async Task<bool> GetCachedLocation()
{
    try
    {
        Location location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

        if (location != null)
        {
            _lat = location.Latitude;
            _lon = location.Longitude;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            await GetCurrentLocation();
        }
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx) { 
        Console.WriteLine(fnsEx.Message);
    }
    catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fneEx.Message);
    }
    catch (PermissionException pEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pEx.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return true;
}
```

If there is no existing Location cached, it runs this:

```
public async Task<bool> GetCurrentLocation()
{
    try
    {
        _isCheckingLocation = true;

        GeolocationRequest request = new(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Location location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

        if (location != null)
            _lat = location.Latitude;
            _lon = location.Longitude;
            return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Unable to get location
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        _isCheckingLocation = false;
    }
}
```

It never gets out of the call to GetLocationAsync(), just hangs. I've tried putting WriteLines above and below the call, and only the one preceding it prints, so it does never come back out.

I've seen a fair few posts about this sort of thing, although none of those solutions have worked in my instance. I've tried playing around the with request timeout interval, to no avail. I've also tried using the overload taking zero params, which also hangs.

I feel I may be missing something obvious. Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: Please take the [tour]. You'll notice that no other questions here have [solved] in the titles. Answers go down there.

Comment: Also read [answer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
GetCachedLocation().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

That kind of blocking on asynchronous code (while within a one-thread-at-a-time synchronization context, in this case, a UI thread) [will cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I describe on my blog.

To solve it, use `await` instad:

```
await GetCachedLocation();
```

`await` is the natural way to consume asynchronous code. Skipping the `await`, discarding the returned task, and blocking on the returned task are all unusual scenarios. This guideline is commonly referred to as [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#async-all-the-way).